# Is there a way count how many times an async function is called?

Tags: javascript

I have function that uploads files from an array of data links

What I would like to do is if data links array contains 3 files

`const testLinks = 3;` and `async uploadImageData` is fired three times I would like to `console.log` after `uploadImageData` is fired three times.

I am thinking of doing a count but all my testing has the count starting over everytime `uploadImageData` is fired.

**.ts**

```
async uploadImageData(formData: FormData) {
  const testLinks = 3;
  const uploadlink = answerAtachmentUrl;
  const headers = headerLink;
  const loading = await this.loadingController.create({
    message: 'Uploading Photos and Files...',
  });
  await loading.present();
  this.httpClient.post<any>( uploadlink + this.userToken, formData, 
  { 'headers':headers }
    ).pipe(
      finalize(() => { loading.dismiss();})
    )
    .subscribe(res => {
      if (res['success']) {
        setTimeout(() => { this.DeleteAllFiles(); }, 5000);
        this.presentToastPhoto('Photo sync success.');
      } else {
        this.presentToastPhoto('Photo upload failed.');
        let respFail = JSON.stringify(res);
        console.log("respFail", respFail);
      }
    });
    // console.log fires once after count and const testLinks both equal 3
}
```

Comment: Can you show what you've tried?

Comment: Just use a flag variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"I am thinking of doing a count but all my testing has the count starting over evertime uploadImageData is fired."
you didn't post what you tried but you probably did not make the counter a global variable. Your code is clearly part of a larger project so I just made this small test to show that it works with async functions. If it doesn't work, let me know.

```js
var count=0;
async function uploadImageData() {
  const testLinks = 3;
  count++;
  console.log(count);
  if (count === 3){
    console.log('count = 3');
  }
}
uploadImageData();
uploadImageData();
uploadImageData();
uploadImageData();
```

Comment: Thank you sir.  I am keeping the var count inside of the class and not a global variable and moved the count inside of the subscription  to count each time it ran.   Works good